# Delete audio file from storage in recycle view in recording application

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have made recording application in which i have delete button in recycle view. but when i click on delete button there is only remove list item not from storage. 
how to delete audio file from storage when i click on delete button in recycleview?

Recordings Adaptor

```js
package com.elevenzon.mediarecorder;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.SecureDirectoryStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RecordingsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecordingsAdapter.viewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<ModelRecordings> audioArrayList;
    public OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;

    public RecordingsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ModelRecordings> audioArrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.audioArrayList = audioArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public RecordingsAdapter.viewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recordings_list, viewGroup, false);
        return new viewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecordingsAdapter.viewHolder holder, final int i) {
        holder.title.setText(audioArrayList.get(i).getTitle());
        holder.date.setText(audioArrayList.get(i).getDate());
        holder.duration.setText(audioArrayList.get(i).getDuration());

  holder.mRemoveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {

    ModelRecordings modelRecordings = audioArrayList.get(i);
    audioArrayList.remove(i);
    notifyItemRemoved(i);
    notifyItemRangeChanged(i,audioArrayList.size());
    Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Removed Selected item.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   }
  });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return audioArrayList.size();
    }

    public class viewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView title, date, duration;
  ImageButton mRemoveButton;

        public viewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            date = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            duration = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.duration);

   mRemoveButton = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ib_remove);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    onItemClickListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(), v);
                }
            });
        }
    }
    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
        this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
    }
    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int pos, View v);
    }
}
```

RecordingActivity

```js
package com.elevenzon.mediarecorder;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

public class RecordingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<ModelRecordings> audioArrayList;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    double current_pos, total_duration;
    TextView current, total;
    ImageView prev, next, pause;
    SeekBar seekBar;
    int audio_index = 0;
    public static final int PERMISSION_READ = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recordings);
        if (checkPermission()) {
            getRecordings();
        }
    }

    public void getRecordings() {
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        current = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.current);
        total = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total);
        prev = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.prev);
        next = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.next);
        pause = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pause);
        seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekbar);

        audioArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        getAudioRecordings();
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                current_pos = seekBar.getProgress();
                mediaPlayer.seekTo((int) current_pos);
            }
        });

        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                audio_index++;
                if (audio_index < (audioArrayList.size())) {
                    playRecording(audio_index);
                } else {
                    audio_index = 0;
                    playRecording(audio_index);
                }

            }
        });

        if (!audioArrayList.isEmpty()) {
            playRecording(audio_index);
            prevRecording();
            nextRecording();
            setPause();
        }
    }

    public void playRecording(int pos) {
        try  {
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, audioArrayList.get(pos).getUri());
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.start();
            pause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_circle_filled_black_24dp);
            audio_index=pos;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        setAudioProgress();
    }

    public void setAudioProgress() {
        current_pos = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        total_duration = mediaPlayer.getDuration();

        total.setText(timeConversion((long) total_duration));
        current.setText(timeConversion((long) current_pos));
        seekBar.setMax((int) total_duration);

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    current_pos = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                    current.setText(timeConversion((long) current_pos));
                    seekBar.setProgress((int) current_pos);
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                } catch (IllegalStateException ed){
                    ed.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
    }

    public void prevRecording() {
        prev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (audio_index > 0) {
                    audio_index--;
                    playRecording(audio_index);
                } else {
                    audio_index = audioArrayList.size() - 1;
                    playRecording(audio_index);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void nextRecording() {
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (audio_index < (audioArrayList.size()-1)) {
                    audio_index++;
                    playRecording(audio_index);
                } else {
                    audio_index = 0;
                    playRecording(audio_index);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void setPause() {
        pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                    pause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_circle_filled_black_24dp);
                } else {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    pause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_circle_filled_black_24dp);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    //time conversion
    public String timeConversion(long value) {
        String audioTime;
        int dur = (int) value;
        int hrs = (dur / 3600000);
        int mns = (dur / 60000) % 60000;
        int scs = dur % 60000 / 1000;

        if (hrs > 0) {
            audioTime = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hrs, mns, scs);
        } else {
            audioTime = String.format("%02d:%02d", mns, scs);
        }
        return audioTime;
    }

    public void getAudioRecordings() {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        //creating content resolver and fetch audio files
        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + " like ?", new String[]{"%11zon%"}, null);

        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));
                String data = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
                ModelRecordings modelRecordings  = new ModelRecordings();
                modelRecordings.setTitle(title);
                File file = new File(data);
                Date date = new Date(file.lastModified());
                SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy");

                modelRecordings.setDate(format.format(date));
                modelRecordings.setUri(Uri.parse(data));

                //fetch the audio duration using MediaMetadataRetriever class
                MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
                retriever.setDataSource(data);

                modelRecordings.setDuration(timeConversion(Long.parseLong(retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION))));
                audioArrayList.add(modelRecordings);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        RecordingsAdapter adapter = new RecordingsAdapter(this, audioArrayList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new RecordingsAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int pos, View v) {
                playRecording(pos);
            }
        });

    }

    public boolean checkPermission() {
        int READ_EXTERNAL_PERMISSION = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if ((READ_EXTERNAL_PERMISSION != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_READ);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case  PERMISSION_READ: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && permissions[0].equals(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                    if (grantResults.length > 0 && permissions[0].equals(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please allow storage permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        getAudioRecordings();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }
    }
}
```

AudioRecorderActivity

```js
package com.elevenzon.mediarecorder;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

public class AudioRecorderActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView;
    ImageView start, stop, recordings;
    MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;
    CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
    int second = -1, minute, hour;
    String filePath;
    String audioFile;
    public static final int PERMISSION_ALL = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_audio_recorder);
        if (checkPermission()) {
            setAudioRecorder();
        }
    }

    public void setAudioRecorder() {
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        start = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.start);
        stop = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.stop);
        recordings = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.recordings);
        stop.setEnabled(false);
        stop.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.normal_background);
        stop.setImageResource(R.drawable.noraml_stop);
        Recording();
        stopRecording();
        getRecordings();
    }

    public void Recording() {
        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                start.setEnabled(false);
                recordings.setEnabled(false);
                stop.setEnabled(true);
                stop.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_shape);
                stop.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_stop_black_35dp);
                recordings.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.normal_background);
                recordings.setImageResource(R.drawable.normal_menu);

                try {
                    // Create folder to store recordingss
                    File myDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "11zon");
                    if (!myDirectory.exists()) {
                        myDirectory.mkdirs();
                    }
                    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("mmddyyyyhhmmss");
                    String date = dateFormat.format(new Date());
                    audioFile = "REC" + date;
                    filePath = myDirectory.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + audioFile;
                    startAudioRecorder();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                showTimer();
            }
        });
    }

    //start audio recorder
    public void startAudioRecorder() {
        try {
            mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
            mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(filePath);
            mediaRecorder.prepare();
            mediaRecorder.start();
        }catch (Exception  e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //stop audio recorder
    public void stopRecording() {
        stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //cancel count down timer
                countDownTimer.cancel();
                start.setEnabled(true);
                recordings.setEnabled(true);
                stop.setEnabled(false);
                stop.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.normal_background);
                stop.setImageResource(R.drawable.noraml_stop);
                recordings.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_shape);
                recordings.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_menu_black_35dp);
                second = -1;
                minute = 0;
                hour = 0;
                textView.setText("00:00:00");

                if (mediaRecorder != null) {
                    try {
                        //stop mediaRecorder
                        mediaRecorder.stop();
                        mediaRecorder.reset();
                    }catch (IllegalStateException  e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                //creating content resolver and put the values
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, filePath);
                values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, "audio/3gpp");
                values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, audioFile);
                //store audio recorder file in the external content uri
                getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
            }
        });
    }

    //lanuch RecordingsActivity
    public void getRecordings() {
        recordings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                start.setEnabled(true);
                recordings.setEnabled(true);
                stop.setEnabled(false);
                stop.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.normal_background);
                stop.setImageResource(R.drawable.noraml_stop);
                recordings.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_shape);
                recordings.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_menu_black_35dp);
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RecordingsActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }

    //display recording time
    public void showTimer() {
        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(Long.MAX_VALUE, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                second++;
                textView.setText(recorderTime());
            }
            public void onFinish() {

            }
        };
        countDownTimer.start();
    }

    //recorder time
    public String recorderTime() {
        if (second == 60) {
            minute++;
            second = 0;
        }
        if (minute == 60) {
            hour++;
            minute = 0;
        }
        return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hour, minute, second);
    }

    //runtime permission
    public boolean checkPermission() {
        int RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
        int WRITE_EXTERNAL_PERMISSION = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        ArrayList<String> PERMISSION_LIST =new ArrayList<>();
        if((RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
            PERMISSION_LIST.add(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
        }
        if((WRITE_EXTERNAL_PERMISSION != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
            PERMISSION_LIST.add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
        if(!PERMISSION_LIST.isEmpty()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSION_LIST.toArray(new String[PERMISSION_LIST.size()]), PERMISSION_ALL);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        boolean record = false,storage =  false;
        switch (requestCode) {
            case  PERMISSION_ALL: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++) {
                        if (permissions[i].equals(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)) {
                            if (grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                record = true;
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please allow Microphone permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        } else if (permissions[i].equals(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                            if (grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                storage = true;
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please allow Storage permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (record && storage) {
                    setAudioRecorder();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //release mediarecorder
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mediaRecorder != null) {
            mediaRecorder.release();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove file from storage, you have to use `file` class.
Like this:

```
File file = new File(path_to_the_folder,filename_with_format);
if (file.exists()){
    file.delete();
}
```

> Also make sure you have granted the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in manifest.

**Edit**
You are just removing element from the arraylist and notifying your adapter.

Comment: please tell me what should i write in "path_to_the_folder" and "filename_with_format" in my case.

Comment: Path_to_the_folder is the folder path where you save the audio

Comment: I think you are saving file in `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + “/11zon”`

Comment: thanks for reply Umer Farooq. but i need different solution because it is not working. please suggest me different way